# iPhone app 'Pending Developer Release' - can I submit for testflight now with no consequences?

Tags: ios, testflight, submission

My iPhone app is currently in 'Pending Developer Release' status but I'm keen to use testflight for one final smoke test before I release it.

This is a bit backwards as I submitted first, before submitting for testflight.

My question is, what will happen if I click the 'Submit for Beta App Review' button in testflight now. Will it take me out of 'Pending Developer Release status' and force me to submit again? I don't want to go through another week of waiting for approval.

Thanks!

Comment: Intuition says you'll be fine, but I haven't tried it

Answer (score 2):

I worked up the courage to submit for testflight beta review and my app is still in 'Pending Developer Release' (phew!) but annoyingly the testflight status is "waiting for review".

I kinda hoped that since Apple have approved the app to be released into the market then testflight might be ready instantly. Now waiting for the test flight review to test >_<